# Safe & Secure Way to Add Domain to Server

Tags: php, security, apache

I'm trying to find the best way to connect a new domain to the server using PHP. I know it's possible because applications like bitly Pro allow users to connect their domain and bitly begins managing the short domain for them (so they can redirect).

Here is how I imagine it would work, but I want to make sure this is secure, and also want to learn the most secure way to execute this process:

1. User connects domain, domain is validated with regex
2. User verifies domain is theirs (is this really necessary? they can only edit the domain's DNS if it's their domain)
3. Server makes API call to DNS manager to add domain (I'm using Linode, so this is an API call, but would this be a master zone, slave zone?)
4. Application writes new virtual host to httpd.conf
5. App restarts apache

Again, this process could be completely off base, so please let me know what you think and how you would code it

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. and 5. is not neccesary. Just redirect all domains to a script (php/cgi/etc) which handles the domain and redirect.
2. Yes it's not neccesary. But you can check if they already inserted your dns.

Comment: So you mean I should make a zone for the domain -> redirect the domain to my domain (with the script) -> my domain redirects to final location?

EDIT: Read more carefully - I understand now, but doesn't apache need to be restarted (or at least reloaded) after a httpd.conf change?

Comment: No what i mean is, that every domain which points to your server gets the same script. And the script makes the redirection. So you don't have to reconfigure the webserver. So only your main domain goes to the website, all other to the redirect script.

Comment: Yes, I got that. In any event, I need to write to httpd.conf or a file included in it to add the domain, correct? If so, what code would you recommend I use to do that?

Comment: You just have to write a "wildcard" vhost for all other domains despide your main one.

Comment: oohhhhh, so the way you're setting it up, a server would need to be dedicated to the redirection process.